# What's the best practice of calling API data from a function outside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

While working with react useEffect hook, most of the example I came across in case of calling api data in useEffect hook for initiate the component is, calling api directly inside useEffce hook.
For instance,

```
useEffect(() => {
 async function(){
  const res = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${query}`);
  setData(res.data)
 }
}, []);
```

But what about fetch data outside the hook with a method ? For instance,

```
const getData = () => {
  async function(){
  const res = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${query}`);
  setData(res.data)
}

useEffect(() => {
 getData();     // here eslint shows an warning "Promise returned from setData is ignored"
}, [])
```

is there any specific reason for avoiding second example. If not what's the proper way to call api call function in useEffect hook with proper cleanup ?

Comment: The reason for using 2nd example is twofold. Abstracting complexity outside of the react component for reuse in other components. Maximising screen space for this react component

Answer (score 2):

#### In React component file

```js
useEffect(() => {
 loadData(query).then(setData)
}, [query])
```

crate another service file to serve data from API

#### in service file

```
export const loadData = async query => {

  const res = axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${query}`);

  return res.data;

  // You can put this API call in try catch to handle API errors
};
```

Comment: how can I mutate state from service file in that case ? For instance in a try catch scenario, if I want to set `try {...} catch(error){setErrors(error)}`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate function for calling an api is a perfect example of loading data in `useEffect`. You can give it parameters if you would have a paginated endpoint and call it multiple times or add polling to the page to load the data by interval. I can only see benefits by creating a function for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => { fetch("./product.JSON") .then(res => res.json()) .then(data => setProducts(data)) }, [])
```

Comment: the question was about calling api from a separate function

Comment: Can you add details about how the proposed code addresses the problem? Code-only answers are not very helpful, neither for the asker, nor others.